# How to remove the underline of the link text in htm?

Tags: html, hyperlink

[Google](http://www.google.com)

i want to remove underline of the link text

Answer (score 1):

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
} /*use this*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You can also add:

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `text-decoration: none;` as follows:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com">Link</a>
```